# Remove specific request headers set in jQuery.ajaxSetup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I setup some custom headers using

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers : {
        'x-custom' : 'value'
    }
});
```

It will add`x-custom` header for all the ajax request. But I want some specific requests to NOT contain this header.

I tried this, delete header from ajaxSettings before that ajax call and add it back when its completed

```
delete $.ajaxSettings.headers["x-custom"];

$.ajax({
    ...
    "success": function (data) {
        $.ajaxSettings.headers["x-custom"] = 'value';
        ...
    }
});
```

But I feel this is not the correct way, as the request that fired before finishing that call will not get that header. What else can I do please suggest.

Should I add the header back in the next line after `$.ajax` instead doing it in callback?

Comment: a more correct approach could be `delete $.ajaxSettings.headers["x-custom"];
$.ajax(...);
$.ajaxSettings.headers["x-custom"] = 'value';`

Comment: Yes, I have done it that way. Just wanted to find out if there are any other/better way of doing it. Thanks.

Comment: `delete $.ajaxSettings.headers["x-custom"];` did the trick for me. I am using it now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since this question doesn't have any answer that can be marked as Accepted. I am posting the solution.

Looks like adding back the header immediately after the AJAX call would make sense. This way we won't be waiting for success callback and then adding it.

```
delete $.ajaxSettings.headers["x-custom"]; // Remove header before call

$.ajax({
    ...
    "success": function (data) {
        ...
    }
});

$.ajaxSettings.headers["x-custom"] = 'value'; // Add it back immediately
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an ajaxComplete function. It will run after all your ajax requests and do whatever you wish.
Something like this,

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        // Add the headers again.
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers : {
                "x-custom" : "value"
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/).
Also, as of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method **should only be attached to document**.

Comment: This would be wrong, It's same as adding those headers back in the callback, which isn't correct. I only wanted one specific request to not have those headers. So it seems like adding it back immediately is the best bet.